# Redundancy bad log ticks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I plotted a graph in matplotlib, and it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFZlT.png), where the x-axis ticks show correctly :

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot([1, 2, 3], [1,2,3])
ax1.set_xscale('log')
plt.xlim(1,100)
ax1.set_xticks([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
ax1.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
plt.show()
```

Then I adjusted the limits of the x-axis,
    `plt.xlim(1,10)`
Here is the new code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot([1, 2, 3], [1,2,3])
ax1.set_xscale('log')
plt.xlim(1,10)
ax1.set_xticks([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
ax1.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
plt.show()
```

And now there are some wrong numbers that I don't need:

[image]

How may I achieve  the first graph as the small x-axis limits ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem when I updated to matplotlib 2+.  I found the solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42886695/5889620). The problem seems to be the minor ticks, which you can remove with the following command:

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.NullFormatter())
```