# matplotlib figure with logarithmic axis but ticks without scientific/exponential notation

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am making a figure where the x-axis should be logarithmically spaced, but I want to manually set the tick labels, and I want the tick labels to appear in ordinary '%.2f' notation, not exponential notation. The following solution based on [Matplotlib - logarithmic scale, but require non-logarithmic labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431248/matplotlib-logarithmic-scale-but-require-non-logarithmic-labels) suggests to use  ScalarFormatter, but does not work with matplotlib 2.0:

```
x = np.logspace(2, 3, 100)
y = x

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
xscale = ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xticks((100, 200, 300, 500))
xlim = ax.set_xlim(100, 1000)

from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())

__=ax.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of a `ScalarFormatter` is sure possible. You would then need to make sure that no minor ticklabels are shown as seen in this question: [Matplotlib: setting x-limits also forces tick labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42845694/matplotlib-setting-x-limits-also-forces-tick-labels)

In your case the code would then look like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.logspace(2, 3, 100)
y = x

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
xscale = ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xticks((100, 200, 300, 500))
xlim = ax.set_xlim(100, 1000)

import matplotlib.ticker

ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.get_xaxis().set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.NullFormatter())

__=ax.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Because you are hard-coding the min and max for the axis, it looks like you are trying to create the graph one-off rather than programatically for more general data. In this case, and especially because you are already getting a reference to the x-xais, you could place the tick label strings in a list and use the axis method [`set_ticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_ticklabels.html?highlight=set_tick#matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_ticklabels). In general, see the [API for axis and tick objects](https://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#common-and-inherited-methods).

Comment: Thanks Bennett, though I think I must be incorrectly implementing your suggestion. The following does not produce the desired result:  ax.get_xaxis().set_ticklabels(('100', '200', '300', '500')). The API/docs indicate that you are correct, and so do not clarify what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You need a list with length equal to the number of ticks: `set_ticklabels(["100", "200", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1000"])`. `*` works on lists in Python, so I'd use `set_ticklabels(["100", "200"]+[""]*7+["1000"])`.

Comment: Also, when you `set_xlim` I think that will `set_ticks` afresh, overriding the effect of your earlier call to `set_ticks`, as can be seen in your graphic. That's why the length of the list of ticks is not 4.

Comment: Yes, the problem is definitely with simultaneous use of set_xlim. When I remove that line, your solution works perfectly. When that line is present (and no matter where it appears in the sequence), the axis labels are duplicated and overlapping.

Comment: xlim = ax.set_xlim(100, 1000)

xscale = ax.set_xscale('log')

ax.set_xticks((100, 200, 300, 500))
ax.set_xticklabels(['100', '200', '300', '500'])
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%.1f'))

Comment: sorry, comments section is pretty limiting for code (and figures not an option)