# How to format tick labels in a semilogx subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting, subplot

I am trying to change the x_ticks labels of a figure with two subplots to scalar values.
That is, I would like to change the `10**0` and `10**1` to `1` and `10` respectively.

Besides, I would like to set the rest of the tick labels [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

The figure code is this:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.ticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
plt.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 0.3 #set the value globally
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

h1 = 1.5
h2 = 0.5
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(8,10))

#---- 
D = np.arange(0.5, 14.0, 0.0100)
r = np.sqrt((h1-h2)**2 + D**2)
freq = 865.7 
#freq = 915 #MHz
lmb = 300/freq 
q_e = 4*(np.sin(2*np.pi*h1*h2/lmb/D))**2
q_e_rcn1 = 1
P_x_G = 4 # 4 Watt EIRP
sigma = 1.56 #1.94dB
N_1 = np.random.normal(0,sigma,D.shape)
rnd = 10**(-N_1/10)
F = 10 #10

plt.subplot(211)

#
y = 10*np.log10(  1000*(4*1.622*(lmb)**2)/((4*np.pi*r)**2))
plt.semilogx(r, y,label='FLink' )

# 
y = 10*np.log10( 1000*(P_x_G*1.622*((lmb)**2) *0.5*1) / (((4*np.pi*r)**2) *1.2*1*F)*q_e*rnd*q_e_rcn1 )
plt.semilogx(r,y, label='OCM')

plt.axhline(y = -17, linewidth=1.2, color='black',ls='--')
plt.annotate("Threshold",fontsize=13,
             ha = 'center', va = 'bottom',
             xytext = (8.5, -40),
             xy = (4.75, -17),
             arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle="->",
                            connectionstyle="arc3"),
            )

plt.ylabel('Power, $P_t$ [dBm]', fontsize=15, labelpad=10)
plt.tick_params(labelsize=13)
plt.grid(True,which="both",ls=":")
plt.legend(loc='lower left', fontsize=13)
ax1.set_xticks([2, 3, 4, 6, 10])
ax1.get_xaxis().set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.NullFormatter())
ax1.set_xticklabels(["2", "3", "4","6", "10"])


#----
plt.subplot(212)
rd =np.sqrt((h1-h2)**2 + D**2)
rd = np.sort(rd)
P_r=0.8
G_r=5 
q_e_rcn2 = 1
N_2 = np.random.normal(0, sigma*2, D.shape)
rnd_2 = 10**(-N_2/10)
F_2 = 32 
M = 0.25

# Back link
pwf = 10*np.log10( 1000*(P_r*(G_r*1.622)**2*lmb**4)/(4*np.pi*rd)**4 )
plt.semilogx(rd, pwf,label='FLink' )

## 
y = 10*np.log10(  1000*(P_r*(G_r*1.622)**2*(lmb)**4*0.5**2*M)/((4*np.pi*rd)**4*1.2**2*1**2*F_2)*
        q_e**2*rnd*rnd_2*q_e_rcn1*q_e_rcn2  )
plt.semilogx(rd, y, label='B_D Link' )

# 
plt.axhline(y = -80, linewidth=1.2, color='black',ls='--')
plt.annotate("Threshold",fontsize=13,
             ha = 'center', va = 'bottom',
             xytext = (8, -115),
             xy = (7, -80),
             arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle="->",
                            connectionstyle="arc3"),
            )
plt.xlabel('Distance, r [m]', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Received Pow., $P_R$ [dBm]', fontsize=15)
plt.grid(True,which="both",ls=":")
plt.tick_params(labelsize=13)
plt.legend(loc='lower left', fontsize=13)
ax2.set_xticks([2, 3, 4, 6, 10])
ax2.get_xaxis().set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.NullFormatter())
ax2.set_xticklabels(["2", "3", "4","6", "10"])

plt.show()
```

I have tried other posts like [*Matplotlib log scale tick label number formatting*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920233/matplotlib-log-scale-tick-label-number-formatting/33213196)
but it does not work in my plot.

For example,
I have tried

**MWE_1**

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
ax2.get_xaxis().set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.NullFormatter())
```

and, also this other change,

**MWE_2**

```
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
for axis in [ax1.xaxis, ax2.xaxis]:
    axis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
```

and, this solution

**MWE_3**

```
import matplotlib.ticker
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.get_xaxis().set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.NullFormatter())
```

All these MWE leave the figure of the above code with the same x_tick labels format.

Regards.

Comment: I guess it would be helpful to show in how far "it does not work". Provide a [mcve].

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest You are right. I have edited the question with two tests to change the format to the scalar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matplotlib figure with logarithmic axis but ticks without scientific/exponential notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45419316/matplotlib-figure-with-logarithmic-axis-but-ticks-without-scientific-exponential)

Comment: @wwii  I have tested the solution of that post but leave the format the same.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with just the data (minimal/fake) being plotted, and the code necessary to reproduce the plot with tick labels you don't like.

Comment: Did you work through the [tick formatter example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html) ? Might be worthwhile to familiarize yourself with the [differnt ways to access the axis ticks](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/artists.html#axis-containers)

Comment: @wwii I have tested the NullFormatter() and the ScalarFormatter(). I have added the code of the plot and three different MWE solutions which not work

Comment: Yeah, but first reduce your example code. The problem lies elsewhere, namely in the fact that `ax1` and `ax2` are not the axes you think you are using for plotting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a mcve with *exponential* tick labels:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.array([10**i for i in range(10)])
y = np.arange(x.shape[0])
fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=1)
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.7, hspace=0.6)

ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2.plot(x,y*3)

ax1.semilogx()
ax2.semilogx()
```

And two ways to format the xaxis tick labels.

```
# scaler formatter
f1 = mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter()
f1.set_scientific(False)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(f1)

# string formatter
f2 = mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:.0f}')
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(f2)

plt.show()
plt.close()
```